# How to translate "Always studying, never learning" (study vs learned, read vs understand, always vs forever vs never, mastery vs proficiency)

Tags: translation, grammar, chengyu

My friend observed that I like to study Mandarin.
It's true, I have been studying for many years, but I'm not very good...

So I want to be modest and say something like this:

> Always studying, never learning

In other words, I have been (and will always be) **trying to learn** Chinese/Mandarin, but I will never **master it**! It also describes the frustrating feeling of re-reading a sentence in a textbook many times, but not understanding!

> Forever studying, never mastering

I'm trying to translate this English sentence into Mandarin. Can you grade my translations below?
You see I'm also trying to use some "prosody"/成语 structure... maybe there is an existing 成语 to capture this idea?

Here are some of my attempts:

- 一直学习 从不学到
- 总是学习 从不学会
- 一直学习 从不精通
- 会习中文 不会掌握
- 读中文 从不懂

Here is the research I did

- [SE "Learn" vs "Study"](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/12680/learn-vs-study)
- [SE 学 vs 学习](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/743/whats-the-difference-between-%E5%AD%A6-and-%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0)

  - and [this answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1244/6139) discusses the -会 or -到 pattern to imply I finished studying, so now I learned it! (学会? 学到?)
- [HINative 总是 vs 永远 vs 一直](https://hinative.com/questions/6595317)

  - [another similar question](https://hinative.com/questions/3657564)
- [HINative 精通 vs 掌握](https://hinative.com/questions/5959091)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to translate "Always studying, never learning"

- 學 = to learn/ to study
- 识 = to understand/ to know
- 学识 = learn to understand(v)/ knowledge(n)

Study but never learn = 学而不识 (study but not understand/ not gaining knowledge from your study)

or

有学无识 (have the studying but no understanding)

Comment: Thank you TangHo, since you taught me to use "而", and  taught me how to use "识" to describe "gaining knowledge" (a word @r13 also used ), I gave you accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

学海无涯，唯勤是岸。(“Knowledge is infinite like a boundless ocean; only through diligence in studies can one make accomplishments”).

Xué Hǎi Wú Yá, Wéi Qín Shì Àn.

[学海无涯，唯勤是岸](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%AD%A6%E6%B5%B7%E6%97%A0%E6%B6%AF%EF%BC%8C%E5%94%AF%E5%8B%A4%E6%98%AF%E5%B2%B8)

Its English version should be "Always study, never learned".
(Study is the activity of learning knowledge. You can learn a technology or a skill, but never learned all knowledge.)

Comment: Thank you @PdotWang, you gave a real 成语 that describes my challenge! Also you gave a 4x4 structure example 学海无涯，唯勤是岸

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

Always(总是/始终) studying(**學**習), never(**不**曾) learning(學**识**) - **总是/始终"學而不识"**.

Forever(永远) studying(學習), never(从不) mastering(精通) - **永远學習从不精通** or **永远"學而不精/通"**.

Comment: Thank you @r13, I appreciate your answer because you really tried to capture my English word choices, "Always ... never ...", I think my phrase is an example of ["antithesis"](https://literarydevices.net/antithesis/)/ my "parallel" phrasing... but maybe I should ask English Stack Exchange if I successfully used "antithesis" / "parallelism" :)

Comment: My English wasn't good enough to make a comment on your response, but, I would say "Always....but (never)..." instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer the 4 x 4 structure, how about,

长年苦读, 一知半解

Comment: Thank you @WayneCheah, I do prefer the 4x4 structure! (it seems like a common structure to make something more memorable/poetic, would you agree?) 长年苦读, 一知半解

Comment: To make the 4x4 structure work "poetically", the last word of the two halves should have "opposing" tones, meaning if the last word of the 1st half is on the up-tone, the last word of the second half should be a down-tone, and vice versa. Hence, 长年苦读, 一知半解 would be "Cháng nián kǔ dú, Yī zhī bàn jiě". Now try testing it with your own attempts in the OP?